# ASP Radio Button Null Value

Tags: asp-classic

I have an "edit" form that is pulling data from a specific row. Part of this form includes radio buttons (a set of four). I am able to retrieve the data from the radio button that has been selected but the other three don't have anything and I get a Null Value error. How could I prevent this? I essentially have 1 cell that pushes in the value of the radio button that was selected. In my asp code I have it set up like this:

```
<input <%If (CStr((rsCourseNum.Fields.Item("question1Correct").Value)) = CStr("answer1")) Then Response.Write("checked=""checked""") : Response.Write("")%> type="radio" name="question1Correct" id="question1Correct" value="answer1">
```

this would throw an error if answer0 was in the db since there is no answer1, I'm just not sure exactly how to set this up to prevent it from calling a null value.

Comment: Is this Classic ASP, or ASP.NET? There's a big difference.

Comment: I apologize, asp classic, thread has now been edited to reflect as such.

Comment: There is a really simple method for avoiding Nulls `& ""` just use `rsCourseNum.Fields.Item("question1Correct").Value & ""` I'd class it as a hack but has work so many times for me over the years.

Comment: @Lankymart: heh, I can't believe I didn't know about that. Definitely a hack, but when you're on a deadline (and when aren't we on a deadline?), anything that works is fair game. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What's the `Response.Write("")` for?

You're not getting an error because you're checking a db value that happens to be Null; you're getting an error because you're trying to convert a Null to a string. There are two<sup>*</sup> ways around this. Method one is to not do any data type conversions:

```
Response.Write "<input type=""radio"" name=""question1Correct"" id=""q1c"""
If rsCourseNum("question1Correct") = "answer1" Then Response.Write " checked"
Response.Write " value=""answer1""><label for=""q1c"">Question 1</label>"
```

This will work with Nulls because the comparison `Null = "answer1"` will return Null, which isn't True, so the button isn't marked.

The other method is to explicitly check for Nulls, and only do a data type conversion if the value isn't null.

```
Response.Write "<input type='radio' name='q" & i & "' id='q" & i & "c'"
If Not IsNull(rs("q" & i)) Then
   If CStr(rs("q" & i)) = CStr(answers(i,0)) Then Response.Write " checked"
End If
Response.Write " value='" & answers(i,0) & "'>"
Response.Write "<label for='q" & i & "c'>" & answers(i,1) & "</label>"
```

<sub>* Well, two, uh, "proper" ways around this. There's also the hacky way: append a blank string instead of using `CStr`. (Thanks for the tip, Lankymart!)</sub>

```
If rs("q" & i) & "" = CStr(answers(i,0)) Then Response.Write " checked"
```

Comment: Appreciate your help Martha! Thank you for providing some explaination behind these!

Comment: Super-hacky you don't even need `CStr()` as `& ""` does the casting.

Comment: Ok, it appears to have worked only for the first value, meaning if I apply this same code to the other 4 radio buttons and update the db to say "answer2" the second radio button doesnt seem to collect this imput properly, are there additonal steps I need to put in place when dealing with multiple radio buttons?

Comment: @user2723341, obviously you need to make sure the 2nd radio button is checking for "answer2", not for "answer1". (And so on.) Notice in my second example I'm using an `answers()` array and a counter variable `i`; this would be a snippet from a For-Next loop that defines the radio buttons based on the array. But it sounds like you may need to review some of the fundamentals of html forms, and then possibly post a separate question.